# Show Control Centre and Notification Centre programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

How to show Control Centre and Notification Centre programmatically, for iOS 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

`-[SBControlCenterController presentAnimated:]`

`-[SBNotificationCenterController presentAnimated:]`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my tweak called CCLiveBrightness.

```
[[%c(SpringBoard) sharedApplication] _runControlCenterDismissTest];
```

An equivalent method can be found to show the Control Center.